# How to return a String in an inherited class?

Tags: java, inheritance

So I have created a superclass called "Food" which takes a String called "name" as a parameter, I now want to created an inherited class called "Meat" and give that class the name of "Meat" which it inherits from the Food class. Here is my current attempt:

```
public class Meat extends Food 
{    
    public Meat(String name) {
        String meat = name;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Here is the Food class:

```
public class Food {

    //field that stores the name of the food
    public String name; 

    //constructor that takes the name of the food as an argument
    public Food(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

I'm not currently sure how to write out the Meat constructor to assign the name. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the super constructor from the child constructor:

```
public class Meat extends Food {    
    public Meat(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}
```

Read the [tutorial about super](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the added value of having the Meat class, unless you override methods or add fields or methods. You could just define your meat as Food:

```
Food meat = new Food("Meat");
```

But if you do extend the Food class, your Meat class will have to call one of Food's constructors. The easiest way to do that is by having a Constructor with the same signature:

```
public Meat(String food){
    super(food);
}
```

Note that every Java class has a constructor. If you don't define one explicitly, the compiler inserts a constructor with public visibility and without parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You won't need to do anything else with the `getName()`.

In the Meat class  you can create the constructor like this:

```
public Meat(String name) {
    super(name);
}
```

But if you want to override it then you can do something like this:

```
@Override
public String getName() {
    String name = "Meat" + this.name;
    return name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want all your Meat objects to have "Meat" as name. You should do this:

```
public class Meat extends Food {
    public Meat() {
        super("Meat");
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I call this in the main method so that it prints this String out?